# oracle check if all the values of a column are equal

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two tables

```
       Table 1
    colA  |  colB  | colC
    ------|--------|--------
      aa  |    bb  |   cc
     aaa  |   bbb  |   ccc
     aaaa |   bbbbb|   cccc

Table 2
    colA  |  coly  | colz
    ------|--------|--------
      aaa |    yy  |   zz
     aa   |   yyy  |   zzz
     aaaa |   yyy  |   zzzz


  query1: select colA from table1;
  query2: select colA from table2;
```

How can I check if all the values for colA returned by query1 are matching with all the values returned for colA in query2. the result should be true in the above example.

```
       Table 3
    colA  |  colB  | colC
    ------|--------|--------
      aa  |    bb  |   cc
     aaa  |   bbb  |   ccc
     aaaa |   bbbbb|   cccc

Table 4
    colA  |  coly  | colz
    ------|--------|--------
      aaa |    yy  |   zz
     aa   |   yyy  |   zzz
     pppp |   yyy  |   zzzz
```

result should be false for table3 and table4.

I am ok with a single oracle query or a PL/SQL block.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions for clarification: (1) Are the values in `colA` distinct, or can you have duplicates? (2) If there can be duplicates, what is the requirement? That the same value appear the same number of times in both tables? (3) can there be `null` in `colA`, and if so what is the requirement? That `null` appears in the column the same number of times in both tables?

Comment: Clarifications: 1. No they are not distict. ColA is foreign key in both the tables. Yes we need to consider the number of duplicate values as well. ( thanks for the question wasn't thinking about it at all ).
2. These are foreign keys to the master table (data structure is designed in that way)
3. null values are not allowed so the logic for null values is not needed.

Comment: OK, but that only answers one question. Do you need the same value to appear **the same number of times** in both tables, if there are duplicates?

Comment: @mathguy edited the comment. Yes we need to consider the duplicate values. means the count of duplicate values should also be same. ( haven't been able to use minus for that reason )

Comment: For the same reason you will not be able to use a full outer join, as @Tejash proposed. The solution I offered (based on an idea from 2004, discussed on AskTom, proposed by Marco Stefanetti) takes into account multiplicities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `WINDOWS` function as follows:

```
select case when res = 0 then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end from
(select sum(case when t1.colA is null or t2.colA is null then 1 else 0 end) as res 
from
(select t.*,row_number() over (order by t.colA) as rn from table1 t) t1 full join 
(select t.*,row_number() over (order by t.colA) as rn from table2 t) t2
on t1.colA = t2.colA and t1.rn = t2.rn
);
```

Comment: Alas this won't work when there are duplicates, and multiplicities must match too, not just the distinct values. See discussion in Comments under the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this (not tested, since you didn't post usable test data):

```
select case 
       when exists 
            (
              select *
              from   (
                       select 1 as tbl, cola from table1
                       union all
                       select 2       , cola from table2
                     )
              group  by cola
              having count(case when tbl = 1 then 1 end) !=
                     count(case when tbl = 2 then 1 end)
            )
       then 'false' else 'true' end
from   t
;
```

The hard work is done in the subquery in the `exists` condition. It takes a disjoint union of the values in `colA` in the two tables; then it groups by those values, and it counts - for each value - how many times it appears in the first table and how many times in the second table. If the counts are ever different, then the `select` in the `exists` condition will return one or more rows, so the entire query will return 'false'. Otherwise it will return 'true'.

Your next step will be to ask, "OK, if they don't match, how can I find out which values don't match?"  That is already answered - by the subquery in the `exists` condition.

I assumed that "same values" means "with the same multiplicity in both tables", if duplicates are possible. If you want only the values to be the same, but not necessarily with the same multiplicity, you can add `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clauses in the inner-most subquery.

Comment: select 1 as tbl, cola from table1
                       union all
                       select 2       , cola from table2 .... we don't need select 2 as tbl or some other pseudocolumn??

Comment: Or - actually - sorry; you are asking why `as tbl` is missing? It is not needed; the column name is copied from the first branch of `union all`.

Comment: thanks for the solution.... worked perfectly for my requirement. Marked marked your solution as answer... cheers... :)